# What is the use of absolute, jitter, rescore and bias_match in YOLOv2 net in darknet?

Tags: conv-neural-network, object-detection, yolo, darknet

Can someone explain me the following used in YOLOv2 net in darknet.

```
absolute=1
jitter=0.2
rescore=0
bias_match=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jitter` can be [0-1] and used to crop images during training for data augumentation. The larger the value of jitter, the more invariance would neural network to change of size and aspect ratio of the objects

`rescore` determines what the loss (delta, cost, ...) function will be used

`bias_match` used only for training, if bias_match=1 then detected object will have  the same as in one of anchor, else if bias_match=0 then  of anchor will be refined by a neural network.

`absolute` is not used

Look to great Alexey's answer for more explanation about cfg parameter : https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet/issues/279